# How to Only Catch non-ApolloError Errors with Apollo GraphQL Server

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have an Apollo GraphQL server, where I want to only report internal server errors (not errors extending `ApolloError` like `AuthenticationError`, `UserInputError`, etc.).

Here is the plugin that I wrote that catches internal server errors and reports them:

```js
const errorReportingPlugin = {
    requestDidStart(_) {
        return {
            didEncounterErrors(ctx) {
                // If we couldn't parse the operation, don't do anything
                if (!ctx.operation) return

                for (const err of ctx.errors) {
                    // Don't report errors extending ApolloError like AuthenticationError, UserInputError, etc.
                    if (err instanceof ApolloError) {
                        continue
                    }

                    // report error here...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However `err instanceof ApolloError` returns `false` when I throw `AuthenticationError`, which extends `ApolloError`.

So I tried to check the `class` of the `err` by printing the constructor name and I got `GraphQLError`.

```js
console.log(err.constructor.name)
```

Does anyone know how to avoid reporting all errors extending `ApolloError`?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#omitting-or-including-stacktrace ?

Comment: @xadm I am not trying to omit the stacktrace. I am trying to send myself an email when an internal server error occurs, but not when an error extending `ApolloError` occurs.

Comment: did you read this? ... from this page *'The error instance received by formatError (a GraphQLError) contains an originalError property'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to check whether `err.originalError` (not `err`) is an instance of `ApolloError` like this:

```js
if (err.originalError instanceof ApolloError) {
    // don't report error since it is a user facing error like AuthenticationError, UserInputError, etc.
}
```

credit to @xadm